# Hibernate foreign key mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have an entity A that has a foreign key of entity B:

```
entity A --> id, entity_a_name, foreign_key_entity_B
```

When I call

```
return session.createCriteria(EntityA.class).list();
```

I get the property of entityB inside entity A as well. How do I make it lazy load so it will not load enityB if not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your description what type of relationship you are talking about, but if it is Many-to-One or One-to-One, things aren't so straightforward. If `A.entityB` is nullable (non-optional) then Hibernate is forced to eager-load the relationship in order to see if the property is null. Only by marking the relationship as non-optional (in which case Hibernate *assumes* that it isn't null since it is an error otherwise) can you make it load lazily.

Answer (score 1):

> - @**LazyCollection**: defines the lazyness option on @ManyToMany
>     and @OneToMany associations.
>     LazyCollectionOption can be TRUE
>     (the collection is lazy and will be
>     loaded when its state is accessed),
>     EXTRA (the collection is lazy
>     and all operations will try to
>     avoid the collection loading, this
>     is especially useful for huge
>     collections when loading all the 
>     elements is not necessary) and FALSE 
>     (association not lazy)
> - @**Fetch**: defines the fetching strategy used to load the 
>     association. FetchMode can be SELECT 
>     (a select is triggered when the 
>     association needs to be loaded), 
>     SUBSELECT (only available for 
>     collections, use a subselect 
>     strategy - please refer to the 
>     Hibernate Reference Documentation for 
>     more information) or JOIN (use a 
>     SQL JOIN to load the association 
>     while loading the owner entity). JOIN 
>     overrides any lazy attribute (an as
>     sociation loaded through a JOIN 
>     strategy cannot be lazy).